# Getting Sum of one row SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select

I am currently getting executing a select statement. I just want to get a sum of one of the rows and not the other 3. I have the following:

```
SELECT SUM([Amount]), [Number], [Brand]
FROM [myTable]
WHERE [ID] = '1000'
```

I just want to get the sum of Amount. If I take out Number and Brand and only select Amount it works great, but not with them included... any ideas?

```
SELECT SUM([Amount]), [Number], [Brand]
FROM [myTable]
WHERE [ID] = '1000'
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense; without grouping you would get one single row in MySQL, and the query would fail with SQL Server. You tagged the question with both - which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group it.

```
SELECT 
    SUM([Amount]), [Number], [Brand]
FROM 
    [myTable]
WHERE 
    [ID] = '1000'
GROUP BY
    Number , Brand
```

Comment: Ha ha, you just beat me.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting an error because the other selections are not being used in an aggregate function.

To resolve you may want to try grouping, something like this:

```
SELECT   SUM(Amount) AS Amount, Number, Brand
FROM     [yourtable]
WHERE    ID = 1000
GROUP BY Number, Brand
```

Comment: I'm aware, thanks, we posted seconds apart, see my comment on his answer.